# executable not found in path even if it is in the right directory

Tags: linux

I have a `pg_config` file in my `/bin/` directory, and my `/bin/` directory is in `$PATH`, but when I run `$PATH pg_config`, it says that the file is not found :

[image: $PATH pg_config not found]

Does anyone know where can it come from ?

Update : when i just run 'pg_config', i have this :

```
[root@PF9SODEVSTU048 clickandqualif]# pg_config
BINDIR = /usr/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/share/doc/pgsql
HTMLDIR = /usr/share/doc/pgsql
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/pgsql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/pgsql/server
LIBDIR = /usr/lib64
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib64/pgsql
LOCALEDIR = /usr/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/share/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/share/pgsql
SYSCONFDIR = /etc
```

I should have specified the reason why I wanted to find 'pg_config' in the path.
I have 'psycopg2-binary==2.9.4' in my requirements.txt and it fail when it tries to install psycopg2 with this error :

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

And it's because of this that I want to know if my 'pg_config' file is really in my $PATH

Comment: To check, whether it is in your PATH, you can issue the command `which pg_config`.

Comment: it found it at '/bin/pg_config'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing

```
$PATH pg_config
```

simply type

```
pg_config
```

which will search pg_config in every directory listed in your PATH variable.

Comment: thanks, I edited my post with more precisions

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question: you need to launch this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
```

... and you say that the location of `/pg_config` is the `/bin` directory.
So what's wrong with launching this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /bin/pg_config build ...
```

Comment: when i try this, I have this error :
''python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"